# For azure enterprise app, is it possible to allow app role to be managed by the application programmatically?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

From what I read, AppRoleAssignment.ReadWrite.All should allow application to use Microsoft Graph SDK to do app role management programmatically. But how do I grant permission such that the application principal can only allow to manage it's own role but not other enterprise application?

The goal is to build a role management page in the web application to allow designated users to add/remove user to an app role for the same application without granting them access to the Azure portal.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it's impossible currently.

Although we can add the user as the admin of the application principal on Azure portal and then we can do anything to the application principal on Azure portal, calling Microsoft Graph is different. It has to rely on the permission of Azure AD app.

But the Microsoft Graph permission `AppRoleAssignment.ReadWrite.All` is for all the application principals.

If you click on "F12" to open the developer tool of Chrome, you will find that the Azure Portal is using another API to finish the operation.

I tried to add my user as the admin of only one application principal through Powershell, but it still doesn't work for Microsoft Graph.

You can go to [Microsoft Graph user voice](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests) to make a request to get the attention of the product group.